# Possible to determine the sign based on individual values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

I have a list of positive and negative integers and I wondered if there was a way to determine if the total of those values would be positive or negative, without actually summing the individual values.

Below is a table of data that I am working with.  I want to determine if the total of Column 2 is negative, add it to Column 1, if not don't (i.e. if positive, do not add), without actually totalling the values.

If you are interested, the reason I cannot use the total is because the data needs to dynamically calculate at it's lowest grain, here being Team Key.  If Team 14 is selected, it should determine that for Team 14, the signage for Column 2 would ultimately be Positive, therefore do not add to Column 1, otherwise add it.

| Team_Key | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 0 | 40000 |
| 14 | 0 | 240000 |
| 12 | 0 | 25000 |
| 12 | 0 | 69999.9996 |
| 12 | 0 | 433333.3334 |
| 12 | 0 | 11666.6666 |
| 13 | 0 | 500000 |
| 12 | 0 | -6000 |
| 12 | 0 | 276250.0004 |
| 13 | 0 | 279034.2703 |
| 13 | 0 | 20000 |
| 13 | 0 | 53652.1739 |
| 12 | 0 | -50000 |
| 12 | 0 | 58411.6737 |
| 12 | 0 | 39333.3333 |
| 12 | 0 | 8666.6667 |
| 14 | 0 | -31000 |
| 14 | 0 | 175000 |
| 12 | 0 | 14166.6666 |
| 14 | 0 | 4999.9999 |
| 14 | 0 | -500000 |
| 14 | 0 | -66000 |
| 14 | 500000 | 0 |
| 13 | 481938.2609 | 0 |
| 12 | 375000 | 0 |
| 14 | 1350000 | 0 |
| 13 | 532333.3329 | 0 |
| 12 | 29589 | 0 |
| 11 | 46000 | 0 |
| 13 | 100000 | 0 |
| 13 | 13125 | 0 |
| 14 | 84000 | 0 |
| 12 | 9999.9996 | 0 |
| 12 | 10000 | 0 |
| 12 | 658333.3326 | 0 |
| 13 | 99999.9996 | 0 |

Comment: Maybe there isn't a direct answer here, but any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you can't add up the numbers? This should be a fast operation, and it's easy to keep the sum(s) up to date as the data is modified if you really need to.

Comment: In general, no.  You would need to actually perform all of the summations.  There may exist some special cases where you can take shortcuts, or perhaps some chance to memory save if you were to round the numbers first... but you run the risk of the test being inconclusive and so would need to add them all up normally anyways.

Comment: As an aside... it appears you are working in some sort of programming context and are talking about adding decimal numbers together.  You should really stop and ask yourself if this is really necessary to keep the values as decimals.  Whenever possible, they should be stored as integers and division performed at the very end... otherwise you end up with things like [0.1+0.2 = 0.30000000000000004](https://0.30000000000000004.com/).